# ThinkPad T520: Is the DisplayPort only working when using the Nvidia GPU?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, display, thinkpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can T520+Bumblebee run an external monitor via DisplayPort?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104857/can-t520bumblebee-run-an-external-monitor-via-displayport)

Maybe slightly off-topic:

Can anyone confirm that the DisplayPort is hard-wired to the Nvidia GPU? That wasn't the case with the predecessor ThinkPad T510, where I could use the port with the integrated Intel GPU.

I'm on the integrated GPU and xrandr only reports VGA1 and LVDS1. :-(